# The structure of ideals in $C[0,1]$

Tags: ring-theory, ideals

Consider $R = C[0,1]$, the ring of real valued continuous functions on the interval $[0,1]$. Let $I$ be a proper ideal in $R$. Then there exists $S \subset [0,1]$ such that $I = I_S := \{f \in R : f(x) = 0 \text{ for all } x \in S \}$.

Proof:
Let I be a proper ideal in $R$. Clearly every $f \in I$ has at least one zero in $[0,1]$. We define $S = \cap_{f \in I}f^{-1}(0)$. My aim is to show $I = I_S$. How to proceed from here? Any hints would be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Why do you say this question is "repeated"?

Comment: @rschwieb I remember seeing it many times in SE. Couldn't find it.

Comment: I was going to say if you had seen it then you should not post it. But I cannot find it either. Of course, the question about *maximal ideals* in this ring has been asked dozens of times. But I don't recall anyone asking about the closed ideals.

Comment: What you are saying would imply that $C([0,1])$ is a Jacobson(Hilbert) ring, but if it were I'd expect to find this as a go-to example of a Jacobson ring.  So that makes me suspicious that it is not true...

Comment: This is indeed not true.  Why are you trying to prove it?

Comment: @Eric Wofsey. I am preparing notes to teach a class. For long time I thought my claim is true. Try to prove today but I am unable to and got suspicious. So I asked in MSE.

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully by now you’ve seen, either near the problem you are working on, or elsewhere on this site, that when $|S|=1$ it is a maximal, hence prime, ideal.

If what you were saying is true, all ideals would be semiprime. But it is quite easy to show that for any $x\in R$ not equal to $0$ or $1$, we have $(xR)^2\neq xR$, proving $(xR)^2$ is not semiprime.

For if $(xR)^2=xR$, then $x^2r=x$ for some $r\in R$. However we immediately see $xr$ is an idempotent.  The ring of continuous real valued functions on a connected interval only has trivial idempotents, though.  This means $xr=1$ or $xr=0$.  The former contradicts $xR\neq R$ and the latter contradicts $xR\neq \{0\}$ because $xrR=xR$.

For this reason, your current goal is not attainable.

Comment: I am not familiar with semiprime.  Let me check and accept your answer. Thank you.

Comment: @GA316 By a semiprime ideal $I$ (in a commutative ring) i just mean an ideal satisfying the property that whenever $r\in R$ and $r^n\in I$, then $r\in I$.  any intersection of prime ideals has this property.  In the case above, we see that $x^2\in (xR)^2$ but $x\notin (xR)^2$, so the squared ideal cannot be an intersection of prime ideals.